# How to click from a video link and let it play in an area below?

Tags: html, css, video

I have several videos on my site, they are listed like the following :

```html
<ul id="toolsButtons" class="ahrefs__tools__nav">
  <li>
    <div class="tools-icon">
      <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1nRiiWYgZw target=_blank><img src=Traditional_vs_GATE_s.PNG></a>
      <use xlink:href="#keyword-research-icon"></use>
      <p class="tools-icon__text">Traditional vs GATE</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="tools-icon">
      <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLHfGQlLqtE target=_blank><img src=Guess_GATE_Password.PNG></a>
      <use xlink:href="#competitive-analysis-icon"></use>
      <p class="tools-icon__text">GATE Passcode</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="tools-icon">
      <a href=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tAGemIvUeI target=_blank><img src=GATE_Demo.PNG></a>
      <use xlink:href="#keyword-research-icon"></use>
      <p class="tools-icon__text">How GATE Works</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I create a viewing area below the list, so that when a video link is clicked, it will play in the viewing area?

Comment: as a quick thinking, you may create a hidden `div` containing a `video` tag and place it on top of the page and when a video is clicked you get its `src` attribute and use it to populate the video in the hidden `div`.

Comment: @ths, good suggestion, any sample code I can try ?

Comment: the method I suggested may look like [this](http://www.cogentstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/modal-lightbox-squarespace-529x270.jpg) a blurred division that covers the page in which you put the video.

Comment: @ths, is there some code online that works so I can try it ?

Comment: if the method I suggested is fine to be used for you I can post it as answer.

Comment: @ths, yes, this seems doable, please post the code and I'll try it ^_^ !

Comment: I may take some time cause I'm busy right now, hope you understand.

Comment: check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, I created a `div`, initially hidden, that plays the role of a popup modal that will be showed when an `a` tag that has a `data-target="modal"` is clicked. I made some changes to your `HTML` code that I will cover them in the answer.

**The process:**

When you click a link that has `data-target="modal"` (a link that has an `href` attribute of a video, here I added a `data-target="modal"` to each one just to differentiate these links from the other links that may be present in the page) the modal `div` that i gave it `id="modal"` will be showed and filled with the appropriete video. So, each time a link is clicked its `href` attribute will be placed in the `src` attribute of the `iframe` tag that will host the video.

**The final result:**

*Ps: I'll provide a runnable snippet, but, it may not work as intended due to some restrictions made by Stack Overflow. For that, I made a working [DEMO](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/mGeERb) on CodePen that you can check and play with the code, if you want.*

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal'), closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.close'), ytVideo = modal.querySelector('.content .yt-video'), title = modal.querySelector('.content .title'), anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-target="modal"]'), l = anchors.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
   anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    title.textContent = this.dataset.videoTitle || 'No title';
    ytVideo.src = this.href;
    modal.classList.toggle('is-visible');
    modal.focus();
   });
  }
  modal.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    title.textContent = '';
    ytVideo.src = '';
    this.classList.toggle('is-visible');
   }
  });
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   title.textContent = '';
   ytVideo.src = '';
   modal.classList.toggle('is-visible');
  });
```

```css
#modal {
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   max-height: 100vh;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
   z-index: 999;
  }
  #modal .content {
   width: 55%;
   height: 65vh;
   margin: auto; /* allows horyzontal and vertical alignment as .content is in flex container */
  }
  #modal .content .yt-video {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: calc(100% - 45px);
  }
  #modal .content .title {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 45px;
   line-height: 23px;
   padding: 12px 4px;
   margin: 0;
   background: #007bff;
   max-width: 100%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  #modal .close {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   line-height: 35px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: #fff;
   background: #666;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: background .4s;
  }
  #modal .close:hover, #modal .close:active {
   background: #ef3658;
  }
  #modal.is-visible {
   display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="toolsButtons" class="ahrefs__tools__nav">
   <li>
     <div class="tools-icon">
       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A1nRiiWYgZw" target="_blank" data-target="modal" data-video-title="Traditional vs GATE"><img src="Traditional_vs_GATE_s.png"></a>
       <use xlink:href="#keyword-research-icon"></use>
       <p class="tools-icon__text">Traditional vs GATE</p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="tools-icon">
       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wLHfGQlLqtE" target="_blank" data-target="modal" data-video-title="GATE Passcode"><img src="Guess_GATE_Password.png"></a>
       <use xlink:href="#competitive-analysis-icon"></use>
       <p class="tools-icon__text">GATE Passcode</p>
     </div>
   </li>
   <li>
     <div class="tools-icon">
       <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5tAGemIvUeI" target="_blank" data-target="modal" data-video-title="How GATE Works"><img src="GATE_Demo.png"></a>
       <use xlink:href="#keyword-research-icon"></use>
       <p class="tools-icon__text">How GATE Works</p>
     </div>
   </li>
 </ul>
  <!-- the modal div that will open when an anchor link is clicked to show the related video in an iframe. -->

 <div id="modal" tabindex="-1">
  <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" title="close">&times;</button>
  <div class="content">
   <h4 class="title"></h4>
   <iframe class="yt-video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A1nRiiWYgZw" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
 </div>
```

**Changes that must be done in the `HTML` code:**

- Each `a` tag that holds an `href` attribute for a video that you want it to be showed in the modal must have a `data-target` attribute equals to "modal".
- To display a title above the video when the modal `div` is showed, add a `data-video-title` attribute that equals to some text on these `a` tags. If the `data-video-title` is not present on a link, the title that appears above the video will be "No title".
- As an illustration to the last 2 points, here's an example of a link that will open the modal when clicked: `<a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/A1nRiiWYgZw" target="_blank" data-target="modal" data-video-title="Traditional vs GATE"><img src="Traditional_vs_GATE_s.png"></a>`
- All the videos links (in other words the `href` attribute of the `a` tags) **MUST** be an `embed` link (`https://www.youtube.com/embed/A1nRiiWYgZw` as an example). So, you have to use the link in the `src` of the `iframe` under the `embed` section under `share` section on YouTube. Here are some images to demonstrate that:

[image: FIrst Step]   [image: Second Step]    [image: Third Step]

**Why using `embed` instead of the regular `watch` link ?**

That to prevent Cross-Domain-Policy restrictions. In simple words, by default servers don't allow other servers/sites to fetch their files asynchronously.

**Notes on the modal `div`**

- For simplicity, I didn't done any animations as opening/closing effects, and the modal isn't responsive.
- You can press `ESC` (Escape) button to close the modal.
- A button with a "cross" sign will be placed on the top-right most of the browser window, to close the modal on click.
- The markup of the modal `div` must be reserved to work as intended.

**Why i didn't use `data-href` instead of `href` ?**

I sticked with the `href` on the links to garantee that the video will be accessible even if `JavaScript` is disabled, if so, it will be redirected to the video.

Hope my answer pushed you further. I'm here for any further explanations.

Comment: I tried it, and it works properly, except one thing, while the video is playing, how do I close the playing window, there is no [x] on the upper right corner, I had to use the ESC key to get out, it should have a window close button on the upper right corner corner, also how to play it immediately without user need to click the play button ?

Comment: I tried to adapt your html into my file [ I changed it to a table listing videos ] , but it's not working : see my html code in my edited question.

Comment: you are not using embed links as I told you. And the close button is on the top right of the window with the letter X and when you hover it it becomes red. and you are using `a` tag that surrounds all of your code and that's really wrong try to change it with a `div`. Try to stick to all what I said in the answer. Visit the [demo link](https://codepen.io/Thabet_Sakhraoui/pen/mGeERb) and you'll get more familiar with what I said.

Comment: OK, I got them working mostly, except 2 of them, so why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySqec8WrEQQ can play the video, but https://www.youtube.com/embed/ySqec8WrEQQ can not find the video ?

Comment: but it's working ! and in my demo everything is workking. I provided three screenshots on how to get the suitable link for the video. Please, try to follow all the steps.

Comment: Strange, I ftped the file to a test site [ http://gatecybertech.com/test ], now they are all working, but I still have the following 2 issues : [ 1 ] I can't find the [x] to close the pop-up window, try to see if you can see it. [ 2 ] How to specify to play a video from the time 29:30 in a long clip ?

Comment: put the modal `div` directly before the  closing body tag and tell me what you'll get.

Comment: OK, now it's where you wanted it, but there is no more pop-up window, try it yourself : http://gatecybertech.com/test

Comment: put the javascript code just after the modal `div`.

Comment: you'll get something like this: div id=modal ..... script ..... </script> </body>

Comment: OK, done, now there is pop-up window, but still no close button. I figured out how to start and end at certain time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178653/discussion-between-ths-and-frank).